# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TransactionsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, stripe-payments

I'm completely new to learning how to think, and running into an issue I can't seem to figure out when following alongside a rails tutorial integrating stripe. like I mentioned, I'm still new to learning how to think, and can't seem to figure out what exactly is screwed up since I'm following a tutorial, though not copying and pasting but reading, looking, and writing the code out to build muscle memory. perhaps a spelling error, however, I'm double checking. thanks for your time.

```
    class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
     skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

     def new
      @product = Product.find_by!(
       permalink: params[:permalink]
      )
    end

    def pickup
     @sale = Sale.find_by?(guid: params[:guid])
     @product = @sale.product
    end

   def create
    @product = Product.find_by!(
     permalink: params[:permalink]
   )

   token = parmas[:stripeToken]

   begin
     charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
       amount:      product.price,
       currency:    "usd",
       card:        token,
       description: params[:stipeEmail]
     )
     @sale = product.sales.create!(
       email:       params[:stripeEmail],
       stripe_id:   charge.id
     )
    redirect_to pickup_url(guid: @sale.guid)
     rescue Stripe::CardError => e
     # the card has been declined or
     # some other error has occured
     @error = e
     render :new
    end
 end

 def download
  @sale = Sale.find_by!(guid: params[:guid])

  resp = HTTParty.get(@sale.product.file.url)

  filename = @sale.product.file.url
  send_data resp.body,
   :filename => File.basename(filename),
   :content_type => resp.headers['Content-Type']
 end
end
```

Comment: Where does the error point to? Show exact error backtrace and message.

Comment: according to the tutorial [link](https://www.masteringmodernpayments.com/read/basic_integration) towards the bottom, I'm instructed to open the url to [link](http://localhost:3000/buy/some_permalink) and according to the action controller error, it's stating it can't find product in and around line 5, which this line '@product = Product.find_by!('

Answer (score 0):

Error is in this chunk of code

```
def new
  @product = Product.find_by!(
       permalink: params[:permalink]
  )
end
```

You search for `Product` with `permalink` equal to `params[:permalink]` in your database, but record does not exist and it throws error. You could use `find` without `!` it will not throw error, but then `@product` will be `nil`

Do you really need to find the record in database or you need to create new instance of class. You could use it like this:

```
 def new
  @product = Product.new # is this solution for you?
end
```

Comment: honestly, I'm not sure. again, completely new to learning how to think, and stand up a rails application.